# DataContractSerializer Maintainability/Expandablility

Tags: c#, serialization, data-structures, migration

Since I am pretty new to this I need to get a few opinions. Right now I have done all the data analysis I can do but as we all know that can change tomorrow.

For my new game I am writing a sort of database with a structure like this

```
Database
    SettingsType Setings ;
    Dic1 Dictionary<string, ObectType1>
    Dic2 Dictionary<string, ObectType2>
    Dic3 Dictionary<string, ObectType3>
    Etc....
    //And A lot more I need
```

So I am using a DataContractSerializer to save the whole thing to XML witch works really nice using

```
public void SaveToXML(string PilePath)
{
    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataBase));

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(PilePath))
    {
        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented; // indent the Xml so it's human readable
            serializer.WriteObject(writer, this);
            // writer.Flush(); // Not needed as pointed out by Jim Mischel
        }
    }
}
```

So here is the Question: "What happens if I need to add or remove a field from ObectType1 or even worse add Dic4 Dictionary in the future?"

I have already implemented the code to export the different parts from the database in separate files, So if one part changes I can import the others and only rebuild the ones I have modified,

I'd like to find a way to be able to migrate (Easily) from one to the next structure if at all possible and recover as much data as possible. (inserting data for new fields, and deleting the ones I don't need anymore) How do you professionals do it?

If this is not possible I might as well go write my data as in the DOS days and take full control and slash the file size to 10%, while I am at it :)

Thanks for your input

Napivo

Comment: Have you looked at the MSDN article about [Versioning Strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx)? Also, there's no need for the call to `writer.Flush` there. The writer will be flushed  automatically when it's closed, as part of the `using`.

Comment: I could kiss you... this gets me on my way. implementing IExtensibleDataObject solves at least 99% of my problems. And yes you are right about flush... Old habit of mine, 30+ years of programming in windows does that to you :)